# React.js add a class on socket.on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I want to add a class when socket.on is invoked. So that a widget opens automatically on a specific socket.id.

The intention is that socket.on('startChat', function() { }); adds  so that the Chat.js file starts running.

```
socket.on('startChat', function() {
});
```

My code:

Website.js

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    showComponent: false,
  };

  socket.on('startChat', function() {

  });

  // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
  this.setState(function(prevState) {
    return {
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    };
  });

}

render() {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    button onClick = {
      this.handleClick
    } > Test < /button> {
      this.state.isToggleOn ?
        <
        Chat / > :
        null
    } <
    /div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use state in similar way.\

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `state.showComponent` to conditionally `render()` a component.

Answer (score 0):

It is [convenient](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to attach any handler or listener into the `componentDidMount()` method.
Following the code you pasted:

**Update**

It looks this is not bind even if using ES6 [arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Make sure the constructor is present, and try to bind it back.
Added react class and imports.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Website extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
      isToggleOn: false // I added this
    };     

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    // No if you use the current notation ()=>{}
    // this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('startChat', function() {
        console.log("Chart started!!!")
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    let state=this.state
    state.isToggleOn = !this.state.isToggleOn
    this.setState(state);    
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick().bind(this)}> Test </button> 
        { this.state.isToggleOn ? <Chat / > : null } 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error with this solution: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')

Comment: in which method? line? sentence?

Comment: Here: handleClick() {
  let state=this.state
  state.isToggleOn = !this.state.isToggleOn
  this.setState(state);    
}

Comment: @JJNL77 I updated the answer, notice also the `{this.handleClick().bind(this)}` sentence in the `render()`. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add socket listener to React useEffect() in functional component.
Or if you are using React class component then you should insert socket listener to componentDidUpdate function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).